# Get size of x86-64 instruction

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I need a function which can calculate the length of an x86-64 instruction.

For example, it would be usable like so:

```
char ret[] = { 0xc3 };
size_t length = instructionLength(ret);
```

`length` would be set to 1 in this example.

I do not want to include an entire disassembly library, since the only information I require is the length of the instruction.

I am looking for a minimalist approach, written in C, and ideally as small as possible.

100% complete x86-64 instruction set is not strictly necessary (very obscure ones such as vector register set instructions can be omitted).

A similar answer to what I am looking for (but for the wrong architecture):

[Get size of assembly instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788236/get-size-of-assembly-instructions/23843450#23843450)

Comment: Why, exactly, would you need this outside the context of a disassembler?

Comment: You will end up using library anyway or going to reinvent a wheel. Waste effort apparently.

Comment: SIMD instructions are common, not obscure. Anyway it looks reasonable to adapt that, there aren't many changes (REX and a 64bit immediate load)

Comment: do you want us to point you to existing code or write code for you?

Comment: If there is existing code which does exactly what I have asked, please link to it.

Comment: VTR: although the answer is a library, it is an official Intel library so I don't believe it is subject to being an "opinionated answer". The question and the accepted answer are precise and may be of use to future readers.

Comment: Didn't want to have to include an entire library, but have settled for the accepted answer anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is XED library from Intel to work with x86/x86_64 instructions: https://github.com/intelxed/xed, and it is the only correct way to work with intel machine codes.

`xed_decode` function will provide you all information about instruction: https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html
https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html#ga9a27c2bb97caf98a6024567b261d0652

And `xed_ild_decode` is for instruction length decoding:
https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html#ga4bef6152f61997a47c4e0fe4327a3254

> ```
> XED_DLL_EXPORT xed_error_enum_t xed_ild_decode    (   xed_decoded_inst_t *    xedd,
> const xed_uint8_t *   itext,
> const unsigned int    bytes 
> )
> ```
>
> This function just does instruction length decoding.
>
> It does not return a fully decoded instruction.
>
> Parameters
>
> - xedd    the decoded instruction of type xed_decoded_inst_t . Mode/state sent in via xedd; See the xed_state_t .
> - itext   the pointer to the array of instruction text bytes
> - bytes   the length of the itext input array. 1 to 15 bytes, anything more is ignored.
>
> Returns:
>
> xed_error_enum_t indiciating success (XED_ERROR_NONE) or
>   failure. Only two failure codes are valid for this function:
>   XED_ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT and XED_ERROR_GENERAL_ERROR. In general
>   this function cannot tell if the instruction is valid or not. For
>   valid instructions, XED can figure out if enough bytes were provided
>   to decode the instruction. If not enough were provided, XED returns
>   XED_ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT. From this function, the
>   XED_ERROR_GENERAL_ERROR is an indication that XED could not decode the
>   instruction's length because the instruction was so invalid that even
>   its length may across implmentations.

To get length from `xedd` filled by `xed_ild_decode`, use `xed_decoded_inst_get_length`: https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html#gad1051f7b86c94d5670f684a6ea79fcdf

> ```
> static XED_INLINE xed_uint_t xed_decoded_inst_get_length  (   const xed_decoded_inst_t *  p   )
> ```
>
> Return the length of the decoded instruction in bytes.

Example code ("Apache License, Version 2.0", by Intel 2016): https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/master/examples/xed-ex-ild.c

```
#include "xed/xed-interface.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    xed_bool_t long_mode = 1;
    xed_decoded_inst_t xedd;
    xed_state_t dstate;
    unsigned char itext[15] = { 0xf2, 0x2e, 0x4f, 0x0F, 0x85, 0x99,
                                0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    xed_tables_init(); // one time per process

    if (long_mode) 
        dstate.mmode=XED_MACHINE_MODE_LONG_64;
    else 
        dstate.mmode=XED_MACHINE_MODE_LEGACY_32;

    xed_decoded_inst_zero_set_mode(&xedd, &dstate);
    xed_ild_decode(&xedd, itext, XED_MAX_INSTRUCTION_BYTES);
    printf("length = %u\n",xed_decoded_inst_get_length(&xedd));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't stop after decoding a single instruction, so you need to iteratively perform `xed_ild_decode` until it stops returning `XED_ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT` in order to make sure it only decodes 1 instruction.

Comment: CHRIS, this `xed_ild_decode` is only to decode single instruction, but it will be correct only when last argument is equal or greater than real instruction length. If you think that example code is incorrect, open issue at https://github.com/intelxed/xed

Comment: Xed also has hugest public database of x86/x86_64 instructions: https://github.com/intelxed/xed/tree/master/datafiles with format documented in misc/engineering-notes.txt - https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/master/misc/engineering-notes.txt

Comment: I seem to have some problem using it more than once. Does `xed_decoded_inst_get_length` reset to 0 after each use or does it return total number of bytes decoded?

Comment: Oh you need to call `xed_decoded_inst_zero_set_mode` every single time, not just once.

Comment: Does not reset anything: https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/b42583afd6664acf53928e69d79649327a93d805/include/public/xed/xed-decoded-inst-api.h#L274 - only reads `return p->_decoded_length;`; `xed_decoded_inst_zero_set_mode` will memset the structure to zero: https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/b42583afd6664acf53928e69d79649327a93d805/src/dec/xed-decoded-init.c#L27 `memset(p, 0, sizeof(xed_decoded_inst_t));` and init some fields in it. Sorry, not the 'minimalist approach' you asked, but correct way to find length in complex variable-length encoding architecture modified every year since 1978

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, you can just use [`IDebugControl::Disassemble(..., &end_address)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugcontrol-disassemble) from `dbgeng.dll`. See [this question](/q/31686186/541686) for example usage.