# Can you change the page permissions of a running process?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, x86-64, paging

I thought about writing an assembly stub to call `mprotect` with the page address, but then I would need to run this stub in the same address space of the process, and I do not know how to do that. Is there another method?

Comment: You could intercept page faults in the kernel and change pte page bits for the running process. Very hard, very risky. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: `ptrace` can do things to the memory of another process *without* having to mprotect.  e.g. `ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT)`.  You can also use ptrace to run code like mprotect inside another process, however GDB goes about doing that when you use a GDB command like `print foo()` where foo is a function in the program being debugged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can, given the appropriate privileges. Depending on the situation, you may need `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capabilities. See [this documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) about `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` to know more.

#### Easy-peasy solution using GDB

The simplest way is to use a debugger, for example [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/):

1. Run the target process and get its PID. You can find the PID of the process with `ps`, `htop`, `pidof` and similar commands.
2. Open a terminal and attach GDB to the process with `gdb --pid PID`.
3. At the GDB prompt, check the memory mappings:

   ```
   (gdb) info inferiors
     Num  Description       Connection           Executable
   * 1    process 19433     2 (native)           /usr/bin/ls
   (gdb) !cat /proc/19433/maps
   555555554000-555555558000 r--p 00000000 00:18 5154601                    /usr/bin/ls
   555555558000-55555556d000 r-xp 00004000 00:18 5154601                    /usr/bin/ls
   55555556d000-555555576000 r--p 00019000 00:18 5154601                    /usr/bin/ls
   555555577000-555555579000 rw-p 00022000 00:18 5154601                    /usr/bin/ls
   555555579000-55555557a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
   7ffff7fcc000-7ffff7fd0000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
   ...
   ```

   Note: I use `!cat /proc/PID/maps` instead of `info proc mappings` here because the latter does not show the permissions unfortunately.
4. Call the `mprotect()` libc function to change the permissions of the pages you want. For example here I change a single page to RWX:

   ```
   (gdb) call (long)mprotect(0x555555577000, 0x1000, 0x7)
   $1 = 0  <-- return value, 0 == success
   ```
5. Now `detach` and let the process run with the modified permissions.

You can also write a [GDB script](https://sdimitro.github.io/post/scripting-gdb/) to do this for you automatically. For example, if you know that at some point RDI will contain an address in the page you want to touch, you could do something like this:

```
file path/to/your/elf
# or alternatively `attach PID`

# Set a breakpoint to some known address (assuming your ELF is not position independent).
# You could also do `break some_symbol+offset` if there are symbols.

break *0x123450
command 1
    set $page = $rdi & ~0xfff
    call (long)mprotect($page, 0x1000, 0x7)
    detach
end

run
```

Then in your terminal:

```
$ gdb -x yourscript.txt
```

---

#### Advanced manual solution using `ptrace`

Alternatively, you can leverage the same low level tool that GDB uses under the hood to write a program that does this for you automatically: the [`ptrace`](https://manned.org/ptrace.2) syscall. You can write a program which does the following:

1. Spawn the target process through `fork` + `execve` (or just run it in another terminal).
2. `PTRACE_ATTACH` to it.
3. Peek around with `PTRACE_GETREGS` (save the initial register state for later), `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` (inspect memory), etc.
4. Manipulate the tracee's memory to write a simple stub that calls `mprotect` for you (`PTRACE_POKEDATA`).
5. Force the tracee to execute that little stub.
6. Reset everything back to normal (restore regs, possibly also remove the stub, etc).
7. Detach from the tracee and let it continue executing.

This is of course a lot harder than the debugger based approach, but it can be fun to experiment with. You are basically writing your own very specialized debugger.

See this answer of mine on ["Writing the simplest assembly debugger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016087/writing-the-simplest-assembly-debugger/64024240#64024240) for more information and a code example of what it could look like.

Here's also [a more complex example on GitHub](https://github.com/briceburg/fdclose): in this case the programmer wants to close an arbitrary file descriptor of an already running process through `ptrace`.

Comment: Great, thanks I did not know you could call functions in gdb in the context of the process you are debugging,